# Change vs. changes

Tags: grammar

Is it *grammatically* incorrect to write:
"Intelligence is the ability to adapt to changes" rather than "... to change"?

If yes, what are the grammatical rules that are violated?

Comment: @clare I actually think it is grammatically correct. Someone else claimed that it is incorrect, but did not provide any concrete reason. I find it difficult to argue why it is correct. Sorry for being a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two possibilities use the word "change" in different senses, and both are grammatically correct. "Change" can refer to mutability in general, such as when we say, "change is the only constant", or, "change is necessary". It can also be a count noun, such as, "costume changes", or, "some changes are necessary".

"Adapting to change" *means* "adapting to changes", but the latter construction is a little more concrete.